# Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried firebase authentication to create an user. While creating an user i am getting the following error stack.

```
> 07-27 07:37:26.385 30248-30261/com.belleza.mewChat W/DynamiteModule:
> Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
> 07-27 07:37:26.385 30248-30261/com.belleza.mewChat W/DynamiteModule:
> Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
> 07-27 07:37:27.140 30248-30248/com.belleza.mewChat D/Login:
> createUser:onComplete:false 07-27 07:37:27.311
> 30248-30267/com.belleza.mewChat V/RenderScript: 0xb8b54170 Launching
> thread(s), CPUs 8 07-27 07:37:36.501 30248-30261/com.belleza.mewChat
> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
> com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

I have added SHA key for my project in firebase console. In gradle also upgraded to latest versions.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.belleza.mewChat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.5.1'

    //firebase database,ui
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'

    //firebase auth
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: The authentication failure may be caused by something unrelated to the warning messages.  I see the messages also, even after successful authentication.  What sign-in method are you using?  Have you enabled it at the Firebase console?

Comment: I am using createUserWithEmailAndPassword method and i have enabled Email/password authentication in firebase console. Enabled anonymous authentication also but still couldn't create an user.

Comment: have you resolved this ?

Answer (score 3):

this error may also raise if password provided is less than 6 characters

Answer (score 0):

When I set

```
...
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    ...
}
...
```

in my *build.gradle* this solved my problem.

Comment: Really? Can you please explain a bit more? I'm seeing this error now and then while testing my application. Every time I see it I believe I can no longer retrieve information from the DB

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that error was caused by having an outdated version of Google Play services on my emulator device. The problem was solved by updating Google Play services from the Google Play Store.