# Firebase AuthListener not working

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-authentication

I get the following error:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth
not found
```

My code works perfectly if I decide to handle the authentication inside the `onCompleteListener`, but when I try to handle it from the `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener`, I get an error.

Here's my signin/signup Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

EditText number;
EditText ans;
TextView questionText;
Spinner country_code;
String[] codes;
String c_code;
Button next_button_1;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

Random rand = new Random();

int a = rand.nextInt(10);
int b = rand.nextInt(10);
int c = a+b;

String tes;
String ran2;
String ran1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    codes = new String[] {"+237","+233","+234"};
    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_question);
    questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionText);


    ran1 = Integer.toString(a);
    ran2 = Integer.toString(b);
    tes = Integer.toString(c);
    questionText.setText( ran1 + " + " + ran2 + " = ");

    country_code = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_country_codes);
    country_code.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            codes);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    country_code.setAdapter(adapter);

    next_button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_next_button);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String uid = user.getUid();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("uid", uid);
                i.putExtra("telephone", number.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("country_code",c_code);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    };

    if(next_button_1!=null){
        next_button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                */
                String answer = ans.getText().toString();
                if(answer.equals(tes)) {
                    String telphone_number = number.getText().toString();
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(c_code) || 
TextUtils.isEmpty(telphone_number)) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Empty field 
detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        String email = c_code + telphone_number + 
"mydomain.com";
                        String password = c_code + telphone_number;
                        startSignIn(email, password);
                    }
                }else {
                    a = rand.nextInt(10);
                    b = rand.nextInt(10);
                    c = a + b;

                    ran1 = Integer.toString(a);
                    ran2 = Integer.toString(b);
                    tes = Integer.toString(c);

                    questionText.setText( ran1 + " + " + ran2 + " = ");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your math test answer 
is wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
long id) {
    String c_code = codes[position].toString();
    this.c_code=c_code;
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}



public void startSignIn(final String e,final String p) {
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "email is "+ email +" and password 
is "+ password + "." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(e, p)
             .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>
() {
                 @Override
                 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                     if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Account not 
found.",
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Creating a new 
Account.",
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         createAccont(e, p);
                     }
                 }
             });
}

public void createAccont(String e, String p){
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(e, p)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>
() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication 
Failed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

}
```

My build.gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "biz.batto.mobilemoneymarket"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '    
proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.6.1'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also, I would like to let you know that I have all my SDK libraries up-to-date and the Google Play Services on my AVD is also up-to-date.

From my MainActivity, I try to authenticate the user first, then if that fails, I try to create you an account. When I run this code and test the account creation process (or login process), the new account is actually created in my Firebase Console, but the `AuthStateListener` is not notified.

Hence my second activity is not launched and my user user remains on the same activity without the app crashing. I also get the log on the Android Monitor:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

This started only today. I have been authenticating on Firebase for a while now with no problems. What can i do?

Comment: The error that you are getting is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602672/local-module-descriptor-class-for-com-google-firebase-auth-not-found.

Comment: @Ignacio 'minfyEnabled' true didn't work for me....i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Please refer this link, I have answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43680527/2581109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem, googled a bit I think a maven repository on the gradle
and added this to the project level gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    } }
```

this would solve the problem