# Change DisplayName in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using email registration Firebase. As of now their is no option to set DisplayName in Firebase. So I am redirecting users to a class where they can change DisplayName soon after signing up through email and password.

My problem is I am unable to achieve that. Here's what I have done so far:

```
public class UsernameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private EditText mName;
private TextView btnSignUp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_username);
    //get firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

    btnSignUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            auth = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                }

                if(user!=null)

                {
                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                            .setDisplayName(mName)
                            .build();
                    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(UsernameActivity.this, JokeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            };
        }
    });
}}
```

Below is the image of what I want to achieve.

[image: EditText]

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow this option

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener); //firebaseAuth is of class FirebaseAuth
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

and in your OnCreate() or onCreateView() implment this:

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                if (!LoginFragment.displayName.isEmpty()) {
                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                            .setDisplayName(LoginFragment.displayName).build();
                    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.d("Display name: ", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                LoginFragment.displayName = "";
            }
        }
    };
```