# Can't update user display name and photo url in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used this code sinppet to update the current Firebase user which have signed up using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
    .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
    .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
    .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
            }
        }
    });
```

But when I try retrieve the `diplayName` or `photoUri`, they return null as if they've never been set in the first place.

Comment: You will need to sign out and sign in again, before the profile is updated. This is a known issue that was introduced in version 9.6 of the Firebase Authentication SDK for Android. It will be fixed in an upcoming version.

Comment: Get help from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Comment: Please refer this link I have implemented http://stackoverflow.com/a/43680527/2581109