# Android Firebase Set Display Name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been working with my app and I have set up the authentication method using email and password. I also need to set up a display name for the user which will be used in other activities such as "profile".

I have been using following method, however it does not setting the display name as I don't see it to appear in log cat. Would somebody be able to tell me where I am making mistake or should I use some other method for setting the display name.

Thanks

```
private void registration(){

    final String email = Email.getText().toString().toString().trim();
    final String password = Password.getText().toString().trim();
    final String username = Username.getText().toString().trim();
    final String age = Age.getText().toString().trim();
    final String userID = userAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(username)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(age)){

        showProgress.setMessage("Registration in progress...");
        showProgress.show();

        userAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                    String user_id = userAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DatabaseReference current_user_db = DatbaseOfUsers.child(user_id);
                    current_user_db.child("email").setValue(email);
                    current_user_db.child("username").setValue(username);
                    current_user_db.child("Age").setValue(age);
                    current_user_db.child("uID").setValue(userID);
                    showProgress.dismiss();

                    AuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            if(user != null){
                                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                        .setDisplayName(username).build();
                                user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                                Log.v(TAG, username);

                            }
                        }
                    };

                    //After user is created main screen intent is called
                    Intent mainpage = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainPageActivity.class);
                    mainpage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(mainpage);
                }

                else if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                    showProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Error While Register",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: I think there is a bug in firebase. The user is not set immediatley but when you exit app and reopen it, it will display the name you set.

Comment: Muhammad Farrukh Faizy , I will check this out

Comment: Please refer this link, I have answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43680527/2581109

Answer (score 0):

Take the username along with the intent
Do this way...

```
mainpage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

intent .putExtra("the key you wish to give ex:name ",username);

Then in mainpage retrieve the username by this way

String u_name;

In On create

u_name=Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString("name");
```

Now u can use that username anywhere by accessing u_name